# Порядок вызова функций при инициализации

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

```
#include <cstdio>
struct P { int x, y; };
struct Q {
  int x, y;
  Q(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
};
int one() { std::puts("1"); return 1; }
int two() { std::puts("2"); return 2; }

int main() {
  P p1{one(), two()};
  P p2(one(), two());
  Q q1{one(), two()};
  Q q2(one(), two());
}
```

Почему `gcc` компилирует этот код с порядком `12121221`, а `clang` не компилирует вообще? Если должно компилироваться, то какой правильный порядок?

Comment: Я бы не стал полагаться на порядок вызова функций компилятором

Answer (score 2):

Фигурные скобки (*braced-init-list*) обязывают `one()` выполняться до `two()`, поэтому первый и третий *statement* должны напечатать `12`.

[[dcl.init]/list-4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.init#list-4):

> Within the *initializer-list* of a *braced-init-list*, the
> *initializer-clause*s, including any that result from pack expansions ([[temp.variadic]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/temp.variadic)),
> are evaluated in the order in which they appear. That is, every value
> computation and side effect associated with a given
> *initializer-clause* is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with any *initializer-clause* that follows it
> in the comma-separated list of the *initializer-list*. ...

Для круглых скобок порядок вызова `one()` и `two()` (**не порядок инициализации**) описывается правилами порядка вызова аргументов некоторой функции.

[[dcl.init]/18](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.init#general-18):

> If the initializer is a parenthesized *expression-list*, the
> expressions are evaluated in the order specified for function calls
> ([[expr.call]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.call)).

Которые, в свою очередь, говорят, что порядок не определён.

[[expr.call]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.call#8):

> ... The initialization of a parameter, including every associated
> value computation and side effect, is indeterminately sequenced with
> respect to that of any other parameter. ...

Поэтому второй и четвертый *statement* могут напечать `1` и `2` в любом порядке. Например, `clang 15.0.0` и `gcc 12.2` [печатают разный результат](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:16,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:16,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:16,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:16),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0Astruct+P+%7B+int+x,+y%3B+%7D%3B%0Astruct+Q+%7B%0A++int+x,+y%3B%0A++Q(int+x,+int+y)+:+x(x),+y(y)+%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0Aint+one()+%7B+std::puts(%221%22)%3B+return+1%3B+%7D%0Aint+two()+%7B+std::puts(%222%22)%3B+return+2%3B+%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A//+++P+p1%7Bone(),+two()%7D%3B%0A//+++P+p2(one(),+two())%3B%0A//+++Q+q1%7Bone(),+two()%7D%3B%0A++Q+q2(one(),+two())%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:g122,compilerOutShown:%271%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:clang1500,compilerOutShown:%271%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+clang+15.0.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) для четвёртого *statement*.

---

`clang` не компилирует код в вопросе из-за второго *statement*, потому что на момент 2022 года так и не реализовал [P0960](https://wg21.link/p0960) (принятый в C++20, см. https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html).

Answer (score 0):

А Вы не тестируете порядок вызова функций при инициализации. Вы тестируете порядок вызова функций при вызове другой функции.

Когда Вы вызываете какую то функцию, передав ей в качестве параметров другие результаты других функций, то компилятор может их вычислить в том порядке, который ему нравится. gcc обычно вызывает их справа на лево, а clang - слева на право. Но это личное дело компилятора. Стандарт не требует особого порядка (до 17 стандарта было ещё хуже). А потом, когда он рассчитал значения каждого аргумента, он уже вызывает функцию с готовыми параметрами.

> [C++11: 5.2.2/4]: When a function is called, each parameter (8.3.5) shall be initialized (8.5, 12.8, 12.1) with its corresponding argument. [ Note: Such initializations are **indeterminately** sequenced with respect to each other (1.9) — end note ] [..]

(такое же и для C++14.)

Когда же передается список в фигурных скобках, компилятор вычисляет их в указанном программистом порядке, и только потом вызывает конструктор (функцию) с готовым списком.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization

> The members of the current object are initialized in *their natural order*, unless designators are used (since C99): array elements in subscript order, struct members in declaration order, only the first declared member of any union.

Это объясняет результаты 1, 3 и 4 случая.

заставить скомпилироваться второй случай - `P p2(one(), two());` мне не удалось ни gcc, ни clang. Это очевидно - у компилятора нет подходящего конструктора.